# Service Data Undefined in Controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access a service and then return the response to a Controller for shared data usage. Here is my service which returns the phone List:

```
app.service('DataService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.getData = function(){
        var promise = $http.get('js/products.json').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
}]);
```

And in the controller:

```
app.directive('phoneList',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
        controller: ['$http', '$scope', 'DataService', function($http, $scope, DataService){
            DataService.getData()
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.products = response;
            });
            console.log($scope.products)
        }],
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    };
}]);
```

But when I am logging $scope.products in Console, it just prints undefined. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `DataService` must be a `promise`. So try `DataService.getData().then(function(response) { $scope.products = response });`

Comment: I understand that it must return a promise, but resolving a promise in controller beats me up saying 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.'

Comment: Ok, read my update. You must return the promise in the service.

Comment: Eh .. you keep updating you're code with awnsers. Now my awnser is completely useless lol.

Comment: console.log must be inside the `.then()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise. So in your service you have to return the `$http` call as a promise.

Replace your service with:

```
app.service('DataService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.getData = function(){

        // Create a var. This will hold the angular promise which you have to return later on
        var promise = $http.get('js/products.json').then(function(response){

            // Return the data which can be called inside the .then(DATA)
            return response.data;
        });

        // Return the promise
        return promise;
    }
}]);
```

Then edit your controller to this:

```
app.directive('phoneList',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
        controller: ['$http', '$scope', 'DataService', function($http, $scope, DataService){

            // Handle the promise
            DataService.getData().then( function(response) {
                $scope.products = response;
                console.log($scope.products)
            });
        }],
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Updated the code with your suggestion. Still it is showing undefined error. My AngularJS version is 1.6.4. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Copy and paste the error. So I can see what error you get. If just showing undefined. Then do `console.log(response)` inside your service getData(). Then check if it logs data there.

Comment: @MohitSharma Perhaps create a fiddle. So I can play with it. Right now, there is to less code to give more suggestions.

Comment: Console.log(response) inside the controller the .then() function. Not outside the .then() but **inside**!. What is it showing you?

Comment: I only get alot of errors. Please update without having errors. Thanks!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GtZddBQWIwyLGIDJ6Zwx Added the code to this. With hardcoded data

Comment: Allready seen it. You create so many errors in your code. The solution is allready given in the awnser I wrote upstairs. You have to log the $scope.products **AFTER** you $scope.products. See plunkr. It just works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/tWIUPH7D6WVJHmplfb9V?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for being a bit noob! Yes the code works fine, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

try returning the object after its available from url

```
app.service('DataService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.getData = function(){
        var data = $http.get('js/products.json').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
       if(data)
        return data;
    }}]);
```

Comment: `if(data)` will return `false` if the `$http` request takes some time.